# How can I get data in local storage every login on laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, local-storage, laravel-5.3

I use laravel 5.3

I set my data on the local storage javascript like this :

```
localStorage.setItem('storedData', JSON.stringify(data))
```

Every time user login, I want to add a condition. If the data stored in local storage exists then I want to retrieve that data and save it in the database

How can I do that in a simple way?

Whether it is using ajax?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do this using ajax, because (as the name implies) localstorage is local on the client and has to be sent to the server to save in the database. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Jerodev, Not yet. I am still try finding out the simple way

Comment: You'll need to show us what you're tried, we answer technical questions here, we don't write code for you.

Comment: @Joe, Okay, I will try it. After that, I will update my question. I just want to make sure first, it uses ajax or not

Answer (score 2):

Local storage is accessible on client side using javascript only so if you want to fetch data on server side use session or cookies(if data size is less than 4kb).

If you still want to use local storage than you have to write ajax call to send data to server

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var myData = localStorage.getItem('storedData');
   if(myData == undefined || myData == ""){
    } 
   else{
      $.ajax({url: "dostuff.php",
         data:{data:myData },
         success: function(result){
             localStorage.clear();
        }});
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var checkStorage = storage.getItem('storedData');
    if (checkStorage) { 
        $.ajax({url: "dostuff.php", success: function(result){
            //DO STUFF
        }});
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe give a little bit of information on how tis works for OP. Also, OP did not mention he was using jQuery.

Comment: It's really self explaining, no reasons to NOT use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

1. Set Your value in localStorage while login.
2. Create a common js file and include in the header (for all the pages after login).
3. Inside that,

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    var myData = localStorage.getItem('storedData');
    if(myData == undefined || myData == ""){
     window.location = "/logout";
    } 
    else{
    //Do your ajax and send the data to controller
    }
    });
   ```
4. While loading the login page clear the localStorage data.

   ```
    localStorage.clear();
   ```

Suggestion:

> Better use **session** for these type of activities.